# How to dynamically link tabbable tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I'm making a little app which sorts websites by groups - where the groups appear as tabs in the tabbable navigator (twitter bootstrap). The premise is therefore, for a new tab to appear whenever you add a new group. This is what it looks like at the moment:

[image]

So the part where the new groups show up works perfectly (rendering them by using ng-repeat and going through all of the groups). However, when I click on them, the tabs don't show, i.e. nothing happenes. It worked when I had static tabs.

Here's the relevant html code:

```
<div class="tabbable tabs-left">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">All websites</a></li>
    <li ng-repeat="group in listGroups()"><a href="#{{group.name}}">{{group.name}}</a></li>
    <li><a href="#group" data-toggle="modal">+Add group</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
        <table class="table">
            <tr class="row">
                <th align="center">URL</th>
                <th align="center" colspan="2">Actions</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row" ng-repeat="item in listSites()">
                <td><font color="{{item.color}}">{{item.url}}</font></td>
                <td>Edit</td>
                <td>Delete</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="Social">asdf</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" ng-repeat="group in listGroups()" id="{{group.name}}">asdf</div>
</div>
<script>
    $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
    })
</script>
```

And here's my controller code:

```
app.factory('groups', function() {
var groups = [];
var groupsService = {};

groupsService.add = function(i_group) {
    var group = {"name": i_group}
    groups.push(group);
};
groupsService.list = function() {
    return groups;
};

return groupsService;
});

function listCtrl($scope,sites, groups) {
    $scope.listSites = sites.list;
    $scope.listGroups = groups.list;
}
```

To sum it up, the question is essentially - how do I link tabs that have been dynamically generated to their also dynamically generated content?

Comment: Did you consider using the `tabset` directive from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ ?

Comment: i did not, in fact i only found out about angular and bootstrap a couple of days ago. thanks, i'll look into, but if anyone wants to offer more solutions, i'd be more than happy to listen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing jQuery code and Angular and that causes problems.

For one, the jQuery code binds to `<a>`s already existing when the script is executed; new ones (the ones that Angular creates that is) will not get the event handler. You would want something like:

```
$("#myTab").on("click", "a", function(e) {
    // same as your code
});
```

But you are still mixing Angular/jQuery. And it will probably not work, or work funkilly, because `$scope.$apply()` doesn't get called. Better is to use `ng-click` in your tabs and handle the event in the controller:

```
<li ng-repeat="group in listGroups()">
    <a ng-click="selectGroup(group)">{{group.name}}</a>
</li>
```

(You will have to add the `selectGroup()` method in the controller.)

---

Having said that, you'd better use an existing component library, e.g. Angular UI with Bootstrap, as commented by pkozlowski.opensource.

Comment: your jQuery way works, although now that you've mentioned that mixing jquery and angular is a no no, it would be nice if you could show me what the selectGroup() function would look like? :)

Comment: (1) Mixing jQuery+Angular like that will probably cause trouble and should better be avoided. It is OK to mix them in Angular link functions of directives. (2) You do not provide the code for the `sites` service. But the outline of `selectGroup(group)` is to feed the `group` argument into `sites` somehow, then `sites` updates `sites.list`. Then the template will render the sites corresponding to the chosen group.